# Algorithm to merge similar text by keeping the same sequence (ex: deduplicate log file)

Tags: string, algorithm, logging, merge, duplicates

I want to group similar text on a log file

example input:

```
user_id:1234 image_id:1234 seq:1: failed to upload data
user_id:12 image_id:234 seq:2: failed to upload data
user_id:34 image_id:123 seq:3: failed to upload data
fail processing data for user_id:12 image_23
fail processing data for user_id:12 image_23
```

expected output:

```
user_id:____ image_id:____ seq:_ failed to upload data -> 3
fail processing data for user_id:__ image___ -> 2
```

What I tried is using python SequenceMatcher: (pseudo code)

```
sms = {}
for err in errors:
    for pattern in errors_map.keys():
        # SequencMatcher caches information gathered about second sequence:
        sms.setdefault(pattern, SequenceMatcher(b=pattern, autojunk=False))
        s = sms[pattern]
        s.set_seq1(err)

        # check some thresshold
        if s.quick_ratio() <= similarity_threshold:
            continue
        matching_blocks = s.get_matching_blocks()

        # if ratio >= similarity_threshold,
        # and the first matching block is located at the beginning,
        # and the size of the first matching block > 10,
        # construct the whole string & replace non matching word with _
        if matching_blocks[0][0] == 0 and matching_blocks[0][1] == 0 and matching_blocks[0][2] > 10:
            mblocks = []
            prev_a = prev_l = 0
            for a, b, l in matching_blocks:
                if l > 0:
                    if prev_l > 0:
                        len_non_matching = len(err[prev_a + prev_l:a])
                        mblocks.append('_' * len_non_matching)
                    mblocks.append(err[a:a + l])
                    prev_a = a
                    prev_l = l
            mblocks = ''.join(mblocks)
```

The result is not that good. I'm wondering if there is a better approach or library that does this already?

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be to cluster the strings and then search for the [Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) within each cluster.

In the general case you could use [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for clustering (depending on the assumptions you have K-Means or DBSCAN could make sense). Computing the LCSS will be 
NP-Hard if you have no other assumptions on you strings.

A more approximate algorithm could only look at the tokens ("user_id", "1234","image_id",...). Use a set based distance (e.g., [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)). Then relaxing the LCSS you could look for most common tokens within each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the OpenAI Embeddings API for clustering. [This tools](https://www.dataharmonizer.com) works quiet well with CSV file based on this model.